# How to upgrade to IOS5?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, ios5

I am using XCode 4.0 and it support base sdk upto 4.3.

Now my question is that can we go up to base SDK 5.0 with XCode 4.0? If yes please let me know how can i upgrade the Base SDK to 5.0?

In short i want to give support for IOS 5 devices as they are not able to run my application at moment.

Many Thanks,
Jigar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.you should download the xcode 4.2 for sdk 5.0 it will also support sdk 4.3. if you need both the xcode 4 and xcode 4.2 it's fairly easy to do. When running the installer, just change "Install location" to something other than /Developer

To change the install location: On the 'Installation Type' screen within the installer you'll notice that the 'Developer' folder listed next to the top install item is actually a dropdown - click this then choose 'Other..' to select a custom location.

### for Snow Leopard

Xcode 4.2 with SDK 5 works fine on Snow Leopard. You can download it from the iOS Dev Center. You need to have a paid developer account to see these versions of Xcode. It's right below Xcode 4.2.1 for Lion (as of 2011-12-13): [link for snow leopard download](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#downloads)